# Fancybox doesn't open video files in popup using Parallax website theme

Tags: jquery, fancybox, parallax

I am building a site at http://papermachinesfilms.com/new/

In the Portfolio section, there are 2 images and 4 videos. The 2 images open in fancybox as they should. The 4 videos load in the same page rather than in fancybox. The code for all 6 links contains `class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery"`.

Here is the code to one of the videos that isn't working:

```
<article class="portfolio print-design applications">
    <img src="images/placeholders/esta-livio-official.jpg" alt="Esta Livio - Aakheya See (Official Video)" title="Esta Livio - Aakheya See (Official Video)" width="263" height="197" />
    <div class="portfolio-detail">
         <h6>Esta Livio - Aakheya See (Official Video)</h6>
        <span>Advertisements</span>
        <a href="//player.vimeo.com/video/87942768?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" class="fancybox-media" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Esta Livio">
            <span class="portfolio-zoom"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</article>
```

I am using jquery.fancybox.min.js

The code for the fancybox media selector is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
openEffect  : 'none',
closeEffect : 'none',
helpers : {
media : {}
}
});
});
```

Comment: I guess you need to include fancybox media helper js file and initialize it within your custom script. Look for that in the docs. BTW, you also need to include your code in your question along the link, otherwise this will become irrelevant if the link changes or is broken

Comment: I tried using the media helper and also tried the iframe type and neither work. I know that fancybox is working because the images work just fine. It is just the videos that open in the parent page rather than a popup.

Comment: It would be a good idea if you also include your jQuery code

Comment: I went ahead and directly copied the code from the fancyBox instructions page and deleted all of the extra javascript code on the page, and the videos from the fancyBox test code opened in the same browser window instead of a popup. I am using the media helper. I am not sure how much of the jQuery code you want posted.

Comment: the relevant code (hint: the one you use to bind fancybox to a specific selector) ... am I asking too much?

Comment: I added the code. Sorry about all the newbie questions.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine http://jsfiddle.net/bhoaop4t/ maybe another script is conflicting (player.js?)